# store onion address inside yubikey

Tags: tor, yubikey

I would like to be able to save an onion (v3) address, without the final string `.onion` inside a yubikey safely.
I want the yubikey that provide this address in plain text at the touch event.
I have tried storing them in address slot 2 as a Static-Password, using ykman-gui and yubikey-personalization-gui, but it does not seem to accept the onion format, probably due to length or character format limitations.

Is there any other way to try?
Probably in command line using some poorly documented parameter, or by somehow encoding onion address?

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of the address you want to store? Be aware that a scan code Static Password can not exceed 38 characters in length.
See https://developers.yubico.com/Developer_Program/Guides/Touch_triggered_OTP.html

Comment: OP mentions v3 addresses, and those are unfortunately 56-character (even excluding the ".onion" suffix).